# Simulink, matlab functions

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-coder

i can't find a way to use the same matlab function in more Simulink block. I used function block but in this way each time a have to copy all code changes. What is the best way to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a file named `<function name>.m` that contains your function, then have the function blocks have one line that simply invokes that function.